# Python: I want to rename multiple folders with modified date in its name

Tags: python-3.x

I want to rename multiple folders.

Example folder structure:

```
Main_Folder|
           |winter(2017-12-18)
           |summer(2018-03-26)
```

Many times I save many pictures to many different folders but i can't remember to what folder I saved pictures to.

Example of what I want to achieve:

summer(2018-03-26) when I save new pictures to that folder and I run program 
,I want the program to rename that folder to summer(2018-08-14)<--this is modified date of that folder

```
import os
import datetime

def modifiedFolderName(folderdir):
target = folderdir 
allFolder = os.listdir(target)

for foldername in allFolder:
    checkname = foldername.find("(")
    if checkname != -1 #if that folder don't have modified date skip it
        #need help here 
        time = os.path.getmtime(foldername)
        #
        #
        #
        os.rename(foldername,trimFolderName(foldername)+"("+"new modified date"+")")





def trimFolderName(foldername):
    a1 = foldername
    b1 = a1.find("(")
    a2 = a1[0:b1]

    return a2 #return folder name without modified date


def main():
    modifiedFolderName("") #for folder dir
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Heya :) would not it be better to write python script which organizes your image collection by date, so in the end you would have folders: 2017,2018... with subfolders 1, 2, 3... representing months of that year?

Answer (score 0):

References:

- https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp
- https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime
- https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Solution:

```
time = os.path.getmtime(foldername)
lastModified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time)
lastModifiedStr = lastModified.strftime("(%Y-%m-%d)")
    # just for debugging, to see what it is doing
print("Last modified: %s", lastModifiedStr)
newFolderName = trimFolderName(foldername)+lastModifiedStr
os.rename(foldername, newFolderName)
```